# Calculating the area between shapes in R

Tags: r, area

I am trying to calculate the area generated (in orange) by an arbitrary point in the space.  here are some example pictures of different possible scenarios:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So basically in all three pictures I want to be able to calculate the orange area that is generated from point by drawing a horizontal and vertical line from the point to the blue area.  The idea is simple but actually implementing is very challenging.  I am writing this code in R so any help with R code would be great.  Also, for the third example, we can just assume that the orange area is bounded at x and y equal to 8. And, we also know the coordinates of the green points. Any suggestion greatly appreciated!

Oh an here is my code for generating the plots below:

```
x = c(1,3,5)
y = c(5,3,1)

point1 = c(2,4)
point2 = c(2,2)
point3 = c(0,0)

plot(x,y,type="n",xlim=c(0,8),ylim=c(0,8))
rect(point1[1],point1[2],max(x)+10,max(y)+10,col="orange",border=NA)
rect(x,y,max(x)+10,max(y)+10,col="lightblue",border=NA)
points(x,y,pch=21,bg="green")
points(point1[1],point1[2],pch=21,bg="blue")
box()


plot(x,y,type="n",xlim=c(0,8),ylim=c(0,8))
rect(point2[1],point2[2],max(x)+10,max(y)+10,col="orange",border=NA)
rect(x,y,max(x)+10,max(y)+10,col="lightblue",border=NA)
points(x,y,pch=21,bg="green")
points(point2[1],point2[2],pch=21,bg="blue")
box()


plot(x,y,type="n",xlim=c(0,8),ylim=c(0,8))
rect(point3[1],point3[2],max(x)+10,max(y)+10,col="orange",border=NA)
rect(x,y,max(x)+10,max(y)+10,col="lightblue",border=NA)
points(x,y,pch=21,bg="green")
points(point3[1],point3[2],pch=21,bg="blue")
box()
```

Comment: Are the points guaranteed to be at integer locations?

Comment: No they are not.  I just did it that way for ease of presentation.  Although if you have an idea that works for the integers I would be very interested in hearing about it.

Comment: if the points are at integer values you could store a 2-d grid of 1x1 rectangles. For every blue rectangle, you could label the corresponding 1x1 rectangles in your grid as being blue. Then you could sum up all the non-blue (aka orange) rectangles at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You're working much harder than necessary.  `pracma::polyarea` will calculate the area of any polygon given the coordinates of all vertices.

Comment: It looks like the OP is plotting multiple overlapping rectangles so this function might not help in this particular situation. I guess they form a more complex polygon, though, so it might still work.

Comment: @josilber -- So long as xe can find all the vertices of the orange region, in all the examples shown it's a single nonintersecting polygon, which means it oughtta work :-)

Comment: many of the corners of the orange polygons are not stored in vectors `x` and `y` used to generate the plots; it's not obvious to me how to compute those corner points algorithmically. We could find the points by hand, but of course we could also find the areas by hand.

Comment: @josilber yea my plot if just for reference but all I will have are the green points and blue point to work with.  Visually its not a hard problem to figure out but actually automating it algorithmically is throwing me for a loop

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks for the suggestion but if I could find all of the vertices of the orange region then I could just calculate the rectangles myself and sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the entire plotting region as an unequal grid of rectangles, with x- and y-grid points at the x- and y-coordinates of the rectangle vertices you're plotting.

```
x <- c(1, 3, 5)
y <- c(5, 3, 1)
max.x <- max(x) + 10
max.y <- max(y) + 10
point <- c(0, 0)
x.grid <- sort(unique(c(x, point[1], max.x)))
x.grid
# [1]  0  1  3  5 15
y.grid <- sort(unique(c(y, point[2], max.y)))
y.grid
# [1]  0  1  3  5 15
```

We'll keep track of the grid rectangles we painted orange with the matrix `orange`:

```
orange <- matrix(FALSE, nrow=length(y.grid)-1, ncol=length(x.grid)-1)
```

We'll make a plotting function that labels cells in `orange` based on the passed rectangle, with `(x1, y1)` as lower left and `(x2, y2)` as upper right:

```
plot.rect <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2, value) {
  x1.idx <- which(x.grid == x1)
  y1.idx <- which(y.grid == y1)
  x2.idx <- which(x.grid == x2)
  y2.idx <- which(y.grid == y2)
  orange[y1.idx:(y2.idx-1),x1.idx:(x2.idx-1)] <<- value
}
```

Then, let's plot our orange rectangle (filling in `TRUE`) followed by all the blue ones (filling in `FALSE`):

```
plot.rect(point[1], point[2], max.x, max.y, TRUE)
for (idx in 1:length(x)) {
  plot.rect(x[idx], y[idx], max.x, max.y, FALSE)
}
```

Finally, let's compute the size of each grid rectangle, enabling the final size computation (the `point` I selected at the top corresponds to your third plot; since the plot extends up 15 and to the right 15, it appears to be working as intended):

```
sizes <- t(outer(diff(x.grid), diff(y.grid)))
area <- sum(orange * sizes)
area
# [1] 41
```

Comment: This code doesn't work.  Try the first plot where the point is at (2,4).  The orange area for that is 1 but your code returns 2.

Comment: I had flipped the indices in the function -- it should work now for you.

Comment: I have gotten some bad answers still with the program. Does it work when the blue point falls in the blue shaded region (i.e., area = 0) and does it work if points have the same x or y coordinates (i.e., points falling on top of each other).

Comment: It should work in both cases -- can you give an example of a result that you believe is incorrect? The code is quite simple -- I suggest you read through it and understand what it's doing.

Comment: Actually I did read through and even though they are simple commands the idea still alludes me.

Comment: OK, please give the example point where you're having issues with the result.

Comment: Ok, when I get back to my computer (in about an hour) I'll post an example that breaks.

Comment: So I realized that the code breaks when the point lies outside of max.x and max.y and in those cases it should return 0

Comment: OK, add an `if` statement to check for that edge case. If the code posted solves your original post please remember to accept it.

Comment: Ok I definitely will.  I am still trouble shooting it with more extreme cases but I think you are right that it should work.